# Change data when binding based on a statement

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, binding

What is the best way to change data when binding xml based on a statement?
For example if "direction" is "N" then "North" and so on.

This is my c# :

```
XElement Xmlwater = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

listBox3.ItemsSource = from WindInfo in Xmlwater.Descendants("Wind")
        select new WindDirection
{
       Direction = WindDirection.Element("direction").Value,
};
```

This is the XML:

```
<Wind>
   <direction>N</direction>
</Wind>
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

**1.** You can modify your LINQ query to do the transformation:

```
listBox3.ItemsSource = from WindInfo in Xmlwater.Descendants("Wind")
    select new WindDirection
    {
        Direction = MapValue(WindDirection.Element("direction").Value),
    };
```

**2.** You can implement an `IValueConverter`:

```
public class WindDirectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return MapValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You add this converter to your binding expression:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <conv:WindDirectionConverter" x:Key="WindDirectionConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Direction, 
                  Converter={StaticResource WindDirectionConverter}}" />
```

In both cases I've assumed you have a `MapValue` function which does the value mapping for you:

```
public string MapValue(string original)
{
    if (original == "N")
    {
        return "North";
    }
    // other conversions
    return original;
}
```